# Compare user value to database and show result through ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

Guys m working on my first live project and i am stuck at a point, where i need help with ajax jquery. i can do this with PHP but i wanna do this with ajax.

Here if user enter a product code ,so i want to compare this product code  value into my database and show product name in my other form ,which will open after user input value:

[image]

Here in first field i want product name:

[image]

Here in my table you can see product code and product name:

[image]

[ok so here is my html code in last option when user enter product code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3ByG.jpg)

[Here is jquery i am sending user data to 8transectiondata.php to compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmo26.jpg)

[And this is php file and i want $data['product_name']; to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg9cn.jpg)

Comment: please post your code here. we need to see your attempt at this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Akintunde - I don't, as I can read the OP's mind.  <queue spooky music>

Comment: welcome to the guessing and imagination game lol @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: @Zuber - While I appreciate the attempt, when it comes to coding a picture is not worth a thousand words.  We need to see the html you have, and any code that you have attempted to write for this.

Comment: I see two potential errors. 1. Spelling error in Transection (should be Transaction). 2. Ned Stark would _never_ buy anything from Cercei....

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ok sir , i updated my question , now you can see my code

Comment: @MagnusEriksson haha i know he will never buy anything ,this funny things keeps work more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic answer.

**JS FILE:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myButtonId').on('click', function () {

        var code = $('#myCodeInputId').val();

        if (code !== '') { // checking if input is not empty

            $.ajax({
                url: './my/php/file.php', // php file that communicate with your DB
                method: 'GET', // it could be 'POST' too
                data: {code: code},
                // code that will be used to find your product name
                // you can call it in your php file by "$_GET['code']" if you specified GET method
                dataType: 'json' // it could be 'text' too in this case
            })
                .done(function (response) { // on success
                    $('#myProductNameInput').val(response.product_name);
                })
                .fail(function (response) { // on error
                    // Handle error
                });

        }
    });
});
```

**PHP FILE:**

```
// I assumed you use pdo method to communicate with your DB

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=myDbName;host=myHost;charset=utf8', 'myLogin', 'myPassword');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    exit('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$sql = "SELECT `product_name` FROM `products` WHERE `product_code` = :code";

$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result->bindValue('code', $_GET['code'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();

if($result->rowCount()) { // if you got a row from your DB
    $row = $result->fetchObject();
    echo json_encode($row, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); // as we use json method in ajax you've got to output your data this way
    // if we use text method in ajax, we simply echo $row
}
else {
    // handle no result case
}
```

Comment: Ohk.. i need to use $ajax() ; function

Comment: Yeah of course. Make sure to use a button to validate the product code. If you don't want to, read ArtisticPhoenix solution.

Comment: ok sir thanks , i was using load() function all that time. 
i edited my question you can see my code

Answer (score 0):

I know what you want to do, but without specific code the best I can do is give you a generalized answer.

When a user fills out a field, you want to post that field to the server, look up a product and return some stuff.

The basics are going to look like this.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

     //rolling timeout
     var timeout;

     $('#field').on('keyup', function(e){

        if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);

          timeout = setTimeout( function(){
                 var data = {
                      "field" : $('#field').val()
                 };

                 $.post( '{url}', data, function(response){

                        if(response.debug) console.log(response.debug);

                        if(response.success){
                             //open other form
                             $('{otherFormProductField}').val(response.product);
                        }

                  }); //end post
           },450); //end timeout
     });//end onKeyup
}); //end onReady
```

Then in PHP, you have to process the request.  Pull the `field` from the `$_POST` array, look it up in the Database. Then build a response array and send it back to the client as JSON.  I like to build responses in a structure something like this.

```
 {
    success : "message",  //or error : "message"
    debug : "",
    item : ""
 }
```

Then in PHP I will do this.

```
  ob_start();

     ..code..

  $response['debug'] = ob_get_clean();

  header("Content-type:application/json");
  echo json_encode($response);
```

This way, you can still print out debug info (in side the output buffer calls ) when developing it and don't have to worry about it messing up the Json or the header call.

-note-  Use a timeout, that you reset on each key press (a rolling timeout).  What it does is reset the previous timeout each time the key is released.  That way it only sends the request once the user quits typing (instead of sending request on every keypress). I have found `450` milliseconds to be about the perfect value for this. Not too long not too short. Basically once they stop typing for `450`ms it will trigger the `$.post`